# Table views inside collection view cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

### **The Issue**

I am attempting to use a collection view in a view controller for cards. When a user taps on a card, it expands. At all times, I have a tableview in each card, whether it is expanded or not. I have the data loading in the table views, but only when I tap on a card to expand it or if I scroll collection view cards offscreen and back onscreen. What is a cleaner workflow to doing this that puts tableviews in each collection view cell?

This is in my main view controller:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "productionBinderCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductionBinderCollectionViewCell

    let suck = cell?.detailsTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)) as? DescriptionTableViewCell

    suck?.descriptionText.text = productions[indexPath.row].productionDescription

    cell?.detailsTableView.reloadData()

    cell?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell?.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    let title = productions[indexPath.row].productionTitle

    let luck = productions[indexPath.row].productionImage

    let zuck = UIImage(data:luck!)

    cell?.productionTitle.text = title

    cell?.productionFeaturedImage.image = zuck

    cell?.productionColorTint.tintColor = UIColor.blue

    let backbtn = cell?.viewWithTag(1)

    backbtn?.isHidden = true

    return cell!
}
```

This is in a subclass of the tableview:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "productionDescription", for: indexPath) as? DescriptionTableViewCell
    return cell!
}
```

This is in a subclass of the tableview cell I am concerned with. It only shows the uilabel text when scrolling offscreen or tapping on the collection view cell:

```
class DescriptionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var descriptionText: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    }

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Maybe I shouldn't be using a tableview at all? Thank you very much to all who help. I am very open to criticism and love learning from my mistakes (a little too often). :)

Comment: Is  collection view horizental ???

Comment: yes, it scrolls horizontally

Answer (score 0):

What you need, first of all, is clear definition of views and cells.

- UICollectionview is a collection of UICollectionViewCell objects
- UITableView is a collection of UITableViewCell objects

Do you need to embed entire table view within each card? There you have your answer. You have parent-child relationship between your UICollectionViewCell and UITableView derived classes:

- Derive from UICollectionViewCell - MyCollectionViewCell - this step is mandatory.
- **Inside xib for MyCollectionViewCell, insert a tableview, with horizontal scrolling enabled. (this is an option inside xib attribute editor)**
- If needed to customize, also derive from UITableViewCell - MyTableViewCell. This step is optional.
- Inside MyCollectionViewCell class file, have implementation for table view datasource and delegate methods. That way, each card will have all its table view cell children in one place
- If present, define custom logic inside MyTableViewCell class file
- There is no need to subclass UITableView here. Everything that needs to be customized can be done using subclassing cells.